# Need more examples/ sources, for Ceq Wong language animal prefixes

Tags: morphology, reference-request, examples, language-games, prefixes

[image]

This is just one, I Googled but couldn't find much, any, in fact not even something else than this.

Comment: How frustrating! I remember reading about exactly this but I can't remember where. I'll have a look through my books and see if I can find anything.

Comment: You might get examples at https://corpora.humlab.lu.se/ds/asv/?2&openhandle=hdl:10050/00-0000-0000-0003-6702-D; but that requires asking for access (which will probably be granted).

Comment: @user6276 I was not granted access since 2 days now, I mailed them right when you replied